# arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc can't compile?

Tags: gcc, arm

I made a simple test.c file and then I entered the command and as result compilation fails with following errors:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o test test.c

Assembler messages
Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv5t'
```

So I reentered the command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armb5t -o test test.c
```

but result was the same

```
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv5t'
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Where did you get this toolchain from? It looks like it's trying to invoke the wrong assembler (e.g. using your host's default `as` rather than `arm-linux-gnueabi-as`).